# Should a File be created explicitly when creating a stream?

Tags: java, file, conventions, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I was wondering about a property of Java's `FileInputStream`s (and `FileOutputStream`s as well). When creating them you can use either of these constructors:

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException

public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
```

I often see (and write) code like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("data.txt"));
```

You can see I create a `File` there. I could also do it without it:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
```

By the JDK source code there seems to be next to no difference between how they work. Here is the source for the constructor that takes `String`:

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);
}
```

All of this is basically the same for `FileOutputStream`.

Is using either one of the constructors a convention I don't know of, and are there any benefits to either? Is it a different case with `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: I think FileInputStream(String name) is there just for convenience.

Comment: @holap So there is no real benefit or difference in using either one?

Comment: FileInputStream(File file) will be called anyway, so no there is no difference. Just use which one is more convenient for you case.

Comment: @holap Okay. Add that as an answer, I'll accept it. :D

Comment: One line answer are not accepted :) Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, the first constructor `FileInputStream(String name)` is probably used more often, it is only the second one, which is `FileInputStream(File file)`, which allows for accurate checking of the input file using the `File` class methods before we link it with the `InputStream`.

Furthermore, the process of creating an object of `FileOutputStream` class is not dependent on the existence or possible lack of the appropriate file. When you create an object of `FileOutputStream` class it will create a file before opening it for future writing. But the attempt to open the read-only file will thrown an exception.